# Distributed grep

Tags: log-files, grep

Is there a solution for a distributed grep?

here's the story: I have a bunch of web servers and want to query their application logs (I'm using tomcat, if it matters). I don't want to have to copy the files to a common storage, they are too big, network is espensive and storage is too expensive so I want to keep them on the same web servers. So even haddop+hive or similar solutions won't fly.
So what I'm looking for is perhaps a local agent for which I can send the grep request to all hosts and get the results back.
Anything like that exists?

- No file copying over the network
- No common storage
- Can't install hadoop on the web servers... I just can't...
- grepping text files

Thanks!

BTW, I asked exactly the same question on http://scale.metaoptimize.com/questions/87/distributed-grep but for some reason the server keeps serving me 500s when I try to view this question, so I'm reposting here.

Comment: Is there any way to consolidate your logs via syslog or similar, instead of trying to duplicate your log files?

Answer (score 3):

For simple command runs, such as `grep`ing for a specific string on the server's logs, use a parallel SSH client like [pssh](http://www.theether.org/pssh/) or [dsh](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en).

For more complicated tasks you might want to take a look at [MCollective](http://code.google.com/p/mcollective/).

Answer (score 2):

Might be fun to try this with [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), maybe something like this:

Put the servers in a file `servers.txt`.  Then:

```
parallel --sshlogins servers.txt "grep foo logfile"
```

I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

I use GNU Parallel for that kind of tasks.

```
echo "fgrep -Rl <MyQuery> /var/log/" | parallel --onall --slf servers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply run something like a cron job on your webserver running something like

`grep something /path/to/log | ssh -C LogAnalyser "tee >> log_from_host X"`

If you want to be able to know when the transfert from all host is finished on LogAnalyser you can start by creating a lock file and delete after `tee`.

Comment: distribution isn't the goal, it's a constraint. The log files are already on the web servers, now I need to grep them.
I can't afford to copy them all to a single host or NAS, so I have to keep them in place and now I want to query them...

Comment: Can't you just grep locally ??

Comment: Ok I guess I misunderstood... you want to fetch grep result of local file from X server and not to send file over the network to X server and get the result back... I will update my answer

Comment: if I use the grep and cron technique I need to ssh first to all machines and set up the cron, it's tedious. I want to run ad hoc greps on various files (at the same location on all servers)

Answer (score 0):

You can try MCollective http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective

The description for its website is:

> The Marionette Collective AKA MCollective is a framework to build server orchestration or parallel job execution systems. Primarily we’ll use it as a means of programmatic execution of Systems Administration actions on clusters of servers. In this regard we operate in the same space as tools like Func, Fabric or Capistrano. We’ve attempted to think out of the box a bit designing this system by not relying on central inventories and tools like SSH, we’re not simply a fancy SSH “for loop.”

It's an high complex orchestration system, if you have only to execute some simple logs grep it may exceed your needs.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps something along the following bash loop?

```
export FQDNS="hostname.domain.tld another.domain.tld"
for host in $FQDNS
do
  ssh $host 'grep "andol was here" /var/log/syslog'
done
```

Comment: This will only serially `ssh` into the remote hosts and run the `grep` command. You usually want to do that in parallel.

Comment: True, so I guess it all depends on what number "a bunch" actually translates into.

Comment: And how /var/log/syslog comes here ?

Comment: "a bunch" ~= 50 to 100

Comment: radius: /var/log/syslog is as much a placeholder as "andol was here". I hardly think this question is about what specific grep command to run at which log file?

Comment: Ran: In that case, joschi is probably right about you wanting to do it in parallel.

Comment: @androl I misunderstand his question, I was thinking that he needs to send log from host X to host A, B, C, ...